# Как поставить 2 типа аккаунтов на Opencart?

Tags: opencart

есть задача регистрации аккаунта для opencart. Проблема лишь в том что аккаунтов будет 2 типов, для физ.лиц и юр. лиц. При регистрации пользователь выбирает к какому типу относиться. В зависимости от выбора при оформление заказа и в личном кабинете будут отличаться поля . Вопрос, как сделать различия по статусу?

Answer (score 0):

Большинство таких задач решается через customer/custom_fields (Пользователь - Настраиваемые поля). Что-то более сложное, чем сбор нестандартных данных от пользователя, придётся доиливать.

[первая ссыль из гугля](https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/create-custom-fields-opencart/)